# Android SDK issues

Tags: android

I have recently begun experiencing several odd issues with the Android SDK and I am unsure why they have begun. Example of some of the problems I am experiencing are:

If I am working with the XML layout file and am dragging and dropping widgets onto the screen, I double click to go to the XML so I can the properties of the widget and it will go to the XML and the screen will just be a greyish color and can't see any of the XML, so have to close the XML file down and re-open it again. See Image below

[image]

Or

When I am editing the XML properties, sometimes I will see duplicate lines of the same code and I have to click on it to refresh properly. E.g. I will be using EditText and I will see this

```
   <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="290dp"
    android:layout_width="290dp"
    android:layout_height="69dp"
    android:layout_height="69dp"
    android:background="#f7f7f7" >

</EditText>
</EditText>
```

So I will have to click on those lines to update correctly, and I usually just end up closing the XML file and opening it again to fix this.

I am using MyEclipse 10, was originally using Eclipse Indigo, but had to swap recently as needed it for my job. I didn't have any of these problems when using Indigo. Has anyone else experienced anything like this? And if so, how did you fix it?

Comment: Please try to update your ADT in your eclipse if you dont have updated ADT. Also update your eclipse.

Comment: close and re start your Eclipse.

Comment: Restarting Eclipse does not fix it, this has been happening for a while now. My Eclipse already has majority of the updates installed. Only things I have not installed are add-ons such as Google APIs or Dual-screen APIs and other ones like that. I installed one more update I noticed I had not installed though, will see if that makes a difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue seemed to be resolved, I installed the updates, and it seems to no longer be a concern